# how to use composer packages in CakePHP plugin

Tags: cakephp, composer-php, cakephp-2.0

I'm going to develop a CakePHP 2 plugin which relay on a composer package. That package is installed in "APP/Vendor" directory. And my plugin is in "APP/Plugin".

Shall I put `App::import('Vendor', array('file' => 'autoload'));` in my plugin files?

Answer (score 5):

If the package in `app/Vendor` was installed with `composer`, automatic loading should be taken care by

```
require APP . 'Vendor/autoload.php';
```

in your `app/Config/bootstrap.php`.

However, if it was downloaded and copied over to `/app/Vendor`, you should manually import it:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'packageFolder/filename');
```

The same applies to Plugins. If you declare your dependencies in your `Plugin/PluginName/composer.json`, within `"require":`, these will be installed together with your plugin, and added to `app/Vendor/autoload.php`, so no need to manually import.

If the package was downloaded to `/app/Plugin/PluginName/Vendor/`, you will have to load it via

```
App::import('Vendor', 'PluginName.packageFolder/filename');
```